# Can not see anything created by my organization on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was invited to an AWS organization.
Now, after I logged into AWS Console as root user, I could not see anything created by the organization in (lambda, s3, etc).

Is there any additional step I should take except accepting the invitation?
Or is this some config missing on the organization side?

Thank you

Comment: In AWS, users only have the rights that have been added with policy, even admins.  However, as an admin you can add those rights yourself.  Best practice is often to create other IAM users with more limited rights for different tasks, for example  besides my admin login I have an IAM developer user with rights to only the S3 buckets used for that work.

Comment: Did somebody in the organization actually create something for you to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Organizations is a way of combining individual AWS Accounts into a hierarchy. Billing can 'roll-up' the hierarchy and permissions can 'go down'.

However, when you login to a specific AWS Account, you will only be able to view/access resources **in that particular account**. If you wish to view/access resources in another account within the organization, you could need to use an IAM Role to login to that other account.